# Looping through a list which is a subarray

Tags: arrays, list, prolog, eclipse-clp

I'm using ECLiPSe 6.1. I have an array of variables of dimension `N x N`, let's call it `Vars`. Now I call a procedure with, say, `my_procedure(Vars[1..N,1..2])`.

Inside the procedure (`my_procedure(List) :- ...`), something like `(foreach(X, List) do ...)` is used.
This doesn't work. I have to write something like `L is List` inside the procedure before looping over `L` (instead of `List`) to make it work.

Why is this? And how can I address it? Because later on I try to call the procedure with `flatten(Vars[1..N,1..2])` and then it gets even worse.

I started using [`collection_to_list/2`](http://eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/lib/lists/collection_to_list-2.html) (with `flatten`) to resolve the issue, but I was wondering if there's an elegant way to address it.

Comment: Is it possible for you to upgrade to ECLiPSe 7.0? It has better support for this.

Comment: I'm on Mac. The problem is that it's part of a bigger project which assumes version 6.1... I may install Linux and rewrite it.

Comment: Using collection_to_list/2 (as you suggest) is the right solution.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your work by the way :)

Comment: In case you are not already doing this: you can invoke collection_to_list/2 *inside* my_procedure/1, then the caller does not have to know about it. I.e. `my_procedure(ArrayExpr) :- collection_to_list(flatten(ArrayExpr),List),...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me elaborate a bit, because your question highlights a feature of Prolog/ECLiPSe that regularly surprises users coming from other programming languages:

- Every term/expression is by default just a **symbolic** structure with no inherent meaning
- Any **interpretation/evaluation** of a such symbolic structure only happens in particular contexts, or when requested explicitly

Maybe the most blatant example is with what looks like an "arithmetic expression":

```
?- writeln(3+4).
3 + 4
```

Prolog takes the argument `3+4` simply as the symbolic term `+(3,4)` and passes it to writeln/1, uninterpreted.  Passing a term as an argument to a user-defined predicate doesn't change this, there is no implicit evaluation at call time:

```
p(X) :- writeln(received(X)).

?- p(3+4).
received(3 + 4)
```

If we want to interpret the argument as an arithmetic expression and evaluate it, we have to request this explicitly:

```
parith(Expr) :- Num is Expr, writeln(evaluated_to(Num)).

?- parith(3 + 4).
evaluated_to(7)
```

**Array access expressions** in ECLiPSe behave in the same way.  They are just symbolic expressions until explicitly evaluated by a predicate that understands them:

```
?- Array = [](11,22,33), p(Array[2]).
received([](11,22,33)[2])

?- Array = [](11,22,33), parith(Array[2]).
evaluated_to(22)
```

So, to finally come back to your original problem: when you call `my_procedure(Vars[1..N,1..2])`, the argument that gets passed is the symbolic expression `Vars[1..N,1..2]`, and this is what `my_procedure/1` receives.  To turn that into the flat list that you want, it has to be interpreted as an expression that yields a list, and 
[collection_to_list/2](https://eclipseclp.org/docs/7.0/bips/lib/lists/collection_to_list-2.html) (or, starting from ECLiPSe 7.0, [eval_to_list/2](https://eclipseclp.org/docs/7.0/bips/kernel/termmanip/eval_to_list-2.html)) do exactly that:

```
plist(Expr) :- eval_to_list(Expr, List), writeln(evaluated_to(List)).

?- A = [](11, 22, 33), p(A[2 .. 3]).
received([](11, 22, 33)[2 .. 3])

?- A = [](11, 22, 33), plist(A[2 .. 3]).
evaluated_to([22, 33])
```